# Undefined variable: query - codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, variables

I am getting the message:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: views/main.php

Line Number: 12

This is the code for my controller:

```
function get_all(){
    $this->load->model('book_model');
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->helper('html');

    $data['query'] = $this->books_model->books_getall();
    $this->load->view('main', $data);
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<h1> List of books in library</h1>
<table border="1"/>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Information</th>
    <th>Publisher</th>
    <th colspan="2">Action</th>
</tr>
<?php
if(is_array($query)){

foreach ($query as $row){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row->id."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row->title."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row->author."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row->information."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row->publisher."</td>";
echo "<td>".anchor('book/input'.$row->id,'Edit')."</td>";
echo "<td>".anchor('book/delete'.$row->id,'Delete')."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Edit: This is my model code:

```
function get_all(){

$this->load->database();
$query = $this->db->get('books');
return $query->result();
```

}

Comment: Probably your model isn't returning any results, are you sure that this $this->books_model->books_getall(); is working?

Comment: Hi @Fabio Antunes. Sorry about this but I'm a beginner with CodeIgniter so not up to speed with everything. This is my model: 
    'function get_all(){

 $this->load->database();
 $query = $this->db->get('books');
 return $query->result(); 
    }'

Comment: Did you load the database library?

Comment: @user1766599 -- if that is your model code, you named your function "get_all" but you are calling "books_getall" in your controller.

Comment: Is that in the autoload file @DevinYoung? If so, yes I've done that

Comment: Yes, but please read my other comment. That is probably the issue.

Comment: I have changed the function from "books_getall" to "get_all" in the controller and the error message is still appearing.

Comment: You also loaded the model "book_model" but you are calling "books_model"

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, we are here to learn with each other by either asking or answering. Can you post your model code? This way we can help you in a better way

Comment: @FabioAntunes. Updated with model code :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, line 12 appears to be this line:

```
if(is_array($query)){
```

And the error message is saying that $query is undefined. When you pass $data['query'] through to the view, that becomes $query.

I note your model is also returning $query->result(). This is not correct - result() should be used inside a loop to loop through the results, and you can use num_rows() to test for more than zero results, as in this example:

Model

```
function example()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('books');
    return $query;
}
```

Controller

```
$this->load->model('book_model');
$this->load->library('table');
$this->load->helper('html');

$data['query'] = $this->books_model->books_getall();
$this->load->view('main', $data);
```

View

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        // Do stuff here on each $row
    }
}
```

I suggest you take a look at [this part of CodeIgniter's documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html), which is actually very good.